# Why can't I use č,ć,đ charters in TCPDF table?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I'm building a tcpdf file for my web site, in that tcpdf file ther is a table with some data, But I cant get this charters to work properly. for encoding I'm  using windows-1250.
The charters witch are not working : č,ć,đ. I have tried with utf-8 but still not geting this charters is there something wrong with tcpdf?

here is my php:

```
    <?php

require_once('tcpdf_files/config/lang/hrv.php');
require_once('tcpdf_files/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'windows-1250', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 061');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 061', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

//START OF DATA FOR PDF DOSJE


         $ime = "šiš čevap";
         $prezime = "čušpaiz";
         $rodjenje = "čakardič";
         $odjel = "četnik";
         $radno_mjesto = "čaćijađ";
         $poduzece = "čitluk";
         $putovnica = "čošak";
         $vozacka = "pićkica";


$html = <<<EOF
<!-- EXAMPLE OF CSS STYLE -->
<table width="100%" style="padding:3px;">
<tr>

<td>

    <table border="1" style="border:1px solid grey; width:60%;">

            <tr>

                <td rowspan="3">
                <p style="margin-top:-38px;">POSLODAVAC:</p>
                </td>

                <td>
                Ime firme
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>        


                <td>
                    adresa firme
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>        

                <td>
                    oib firme
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table><br>

    <table  border="1" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; width:60%;">    
            <tr>            
                <td>
                RADNIK: 
                </td>

                <td>
                $ime $prezime
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>        
                <td>
                Oib
                </td>

                <td>
                $rodjenje
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>        
                <td>
                Spol
                </td>

                <td>
                $odjel
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>        
                <td>
                Dan, mjesec i godina rođenja
                </td>

                <td>
                $radno_mjesto
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>        
                <td>
                Državljanstvo
                </td>

                <td>
                $radno_mjesto
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>






EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();


//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_061.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Sou any ideas? Please it isn't sou big of a deal, and it whil help others who whil use tcpdf. Sou please try to help mee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work, but try `iconv`. I had to use it when I was making Japanese PDFs. I don't know what your encoding needs to be, but this is what I used:

```
$newtext = iconv("UTF-8", "SJIS", $oldtext);
```

Obviously change 'SJIS' to whatever encoding you are using.

**EDIT**

Just repeating what I said in the comments below, but hopefully it is easier to read up here:

Try changing the fourth constructor variable to `TRUE`, so it uses UTF-8:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'windows-1250', false);
                                                                    ⇓
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'windows-1250', false);
```

If that doesn't work, I don't know what to tell you :-/

**EDIT (again)**

Probably a silly question, but did you look at the examples?

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.phps

Is there nothing there that can help you?

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**

Okay, hopefully this should do it:

```
<?php 

require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/hrv.php'); 
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 

// create new PDF document 
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'utf-8', false);

// set document information 
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR); 
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni'); 
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 061'); 
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial'); 
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide'); 

// set default header data 
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 061', PDF_HEADER_STRING); 

// set header and footer fonts 
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN)); 
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA)); 

// set default monospaced font 
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED); 

//set margins 
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT); 
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER); 
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER); 

//set auto page breaks 
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM); 

//set image scale factor 
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO); 

//set some language-dependent strings 
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l); 

// --------------------------------------------------------- 

// set font 
$pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 10); 

// add a page 
$pdf->AddPage(); 

//START OF DATA FOR PDF DOSJE 

  $ime = "šiš čevap";
  $prezime = "čušpaiz";
  $rodjenje = "čakardič";
  $odjel = "četnik";
  $radno_mjesto = "čaćijađ";
  $poduzece = "čitluk";
  $putovnica = "čošak";
  $vozacka = "pićkica";

$html = <<<EOF
<!-- EXAMPLE OF CSS STYLE --> 
<table width="100%" style="padding:3px;"> 
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1" style="border:1px solid grey; width:60%;"> 
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"> 
            <p style="margin-top:-38px;">POSLODAVAC:</p> 
          </td>
          <td>
            Ime firme
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            adresa firme
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            oib firme
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table  border="1" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; width:60%;">     
        <tr>             
          <td> 
            RADNIK:  
          </td>
          <td> 
            $ime $prezime 
          </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>         
          <td> 
            Oib
          </td>
          <td>
            $rodjenje
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 
            Spol 
          </td>
          <td>
            $odjel
          </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>         
          <td>
            Dan, mjesec i godina rođenja 
          </td>
          <td>
            $radno_mjesto
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Državljanstvo
          </td>
          <td>
            $radno_mjesto 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

EOF;

// output the HTML content 
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); 


// reset pointer to the last page 
$pdf->lastPage(); 


//Close and output PDF document 
$pdf->Output('example_061.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

If you are using values from your 1250-encoded database, you will need to convert them like this:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('databasename', $db);
mysql_set_charset("cp1250");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `yourtable`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $converted_value = iconv("windows-1250", "utf-8", $row['column_name']);
}
```

I made a test table with 1250 collation in my own database, and used the words you supplied. This worked for me. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Sou I need just to replace ´$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'windows-1250', false);
´ with ´$newtext = iconv("UTF-8", "SJIS", $oldtext);
´ or ? can u elaborate what this function do? I need arabic encoding.

Comment: no, I mean every time you print out a string, you need to pass it through `iconv`. so after you do `$vozacka = $row_print['broj_vozacke'];`, you should then do `$vozacka = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1256", $vozacka);`. Works with Japanese, but I'm not sure it will work with Arabic though, since I know nothing about it :-/

Comment: By the way I'm just guessing about the encoding; it might not be `Windows-1256`, it could be `ISO-8859-6` or something else entirely.

Comment: sou I see, ok I understand. But is there a way to do this for whol html text in document? insted doing this for every string and every word witch contanes č,č or đ.

Comment: I'm not sure :-( Did you try changing the fourth argument in the constructor to `true`? That should make it use UTF-8, which might help: `$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'windows-1250', false);`

Comment: Jes I have tried that this moment, but my document turns blank when I change the fourth argument. And for this example:`$pisti = "Piči čićaa";
$pisti1 = iconv("windows-1250", "UTF-8", $pisti);` When I echo the `$pisti1` I get this `PiÄ•i Ä•iÄ‡aa` this I dont understand why cant I get this charters to work? I have tried the 100 diferent ways... Help!

Comment: I think the `iconv()` arguments are the wrong way round. UTF-8 was first when I did it with Japanese (see my first example). I'm not sure why it was that way, but it seemed to work.

Comment: Believe me I've tried various ways. But did not produce the required results, as it is somewhere already predefined encoding. TCPDF FILE still not giving me the Č,Ć,Đ CHARTERS.

Comment: Then I guess I'm out of ideas. Unless... Are you absolutely sure `windows-1250` is the right encoding? Maybe the original was encoded differently or something? But I'm sure you will already have checked that, eh :-/ If you could link to a sample or something, maybe I could fiddle around with it a bit.

Comment: well thanks sou much for your info and good will, seriously I'd like to find the solution for this sou if you can try anything with the code that I have posted up, I would be gracious. Please try to test the code.

Comment: could you replace the database `row_print[]` stuff with some example text? Obviously I can't access your database :-)

Comment: here you go, I have replaced the `row_print[]` with random words, with č,ć,đ those are the problematic charters. :-D

Comment: wow... I think the problem was with the font! try changing the font from `times` to `freesans`. I had to change the encoding round a bit, but I'll clean it up and post what I got. In the meantime, give it a try!

Comment: you can also use `freeserif` if you want a `times`-like font :-)

Comment: :-) thanks I'l try to do that, I have tryed something like that allredy, i meen changint the font, but then i got the error, but i haven't try this fonts. I hope that this is the right solution. So what should i use for encoding? utf-8 ? or...

Comment: when you take the data from the database, you need to set it to `mysql_set_charset('cp1250')`, like in my example. `cp1250` is mysql's version of `windows-1250`. then you need to use `iconv()` on each row data to convert it to utf-8. tcpdf constructor should be set to utf-8.

Comment: Ihad a network conection problems, so i didn't try jet. But I whil let you know tomorow. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 5):

It will not work with times font.
Our letters works with this font:

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 11, '', true);
```

And UTF-8

**EDIT**
After some time, I think that this is better:

```
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 11, '', true);
```

Comment: This is the way that you can use č, ć, š, đ, and ž characters!

Answer (score 1):

try to use mPDF, it is more convinient and clear to understand ([mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/))
Expamle:

```
            require(LIBRARY . "/MPDF54/mpdf.php");

            $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4-L','','',10,10,20,15,5,5, 'L');
            $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
            $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;

                $header = $view->render('header.phtml');    
            $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
                $footer = $view->render('footer.phtml');
            $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

                $view->client_info = $client_info[0];
                $view->info = $info;
                $view->lots = $lots;
                $html = $view->render('invoice.phtml'); 

            $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
            $mpdf->Output("bidder_$id.pdf",'I');
            exit;
```

Comment: I have finished the whol document in tcpdf sou it wuld be big weast off time if I change the pdf generator now.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the codes like this:

```
č = &#269;
ć = &#263;
đ = &#273;
```

?

I personaly also have better experiences with mPDF.

Comment: I have tried just now with this solution but instead of Đ i get &#272; = Ä• why is that sou, a had finished the document in tcpdf all i had to doe is fix this problem. Sou I'm not gona change pdf generator now at this level. so can please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, some tips:

Like in other answers check your font, it must be unicode...

Then, check your encoding :

You can do it with : mb_detect_encoding.

Like this :

```
$x=$row['adresa']; // $x=test

  echo mb_detect_encoding($x);

  echo $x;
```

end result will be,etc. : UTF-8 test

If is not Utf-8 Tcpdf will show blank page.

Answer (score -1):

```
SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR); 
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni'); 
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 048'); 
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial'); 
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide'); 
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.': Naziv Udruge', PDF_HEADER_STRING); 
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN)); $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA)); $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED); 
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT); 
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER); 
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER); 
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM); 
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO); 
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/hrv.php')) { require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/hrv.php'); 
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l); 
} 
// --------------------------------------------------------- 
$pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12); 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->Write(0, 'Lista čćšđžlanova', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0); $pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 8); 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
$tbl = ' '; 
mysql_set_charset("cp1250"); 
$rezultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE contact_id > 0"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)) { 
$ime=$row['first_name']; 
$ime2 = iconv("windows-1250", "utf-8", $ime);
$tbl=$tbl.' '; 
} $tbl=$tbl.'
Ime i prezime   Datum rođenjačćšđž  Adresa'.$ime2.'nn   BLA BLA BLA BLA';
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, ''); 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
$pdf->Output('Lista.pdf', 'I'); 
?>
```